# Wordpress - Yoast plugin box not displaying on admin page

Tags: javascript, wordpress, yoast

I am facing the issue with yoast plugin wherein the yoast box is not dispaying on admin->pages as show in following link [Yoast box not displaying](https://i.stack.imgur.com/grncD.png). In console, the javascript error is coming as shown in attach image [js error while loading yoast setting page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQcFW.png)

Comment: Please add the code you have tried.

Comment: Please check screenshots on link. Since it is plugins, there is no code added, just need to install from wordpress backend. Earlier the yoast box displaying on add pages page, but now it is not.

Comment: I found the solution. It was jquery ver 1.1 that was generating issue. I updated to jquery 3.2 and the error disappears